# What determines the shape of the WIMP cross-section vs mass limit curves?

Tags: particle-physics, dark-matter, wimps

In figure 5 of [arXiv:1310.8214v1](https://arxiv.org/abs/1310.8214v1), the experiments all seem to reach the lowest cross-sections when the WIMP is in the $40-100\, \mathrm{GeV}/c^2$ range. What is the physical reason for the scale of this minimum?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a competition between two effects. If WIMPs are too light, they don't produce observable nuclear recoils: it's like trying to move a bowling ball by hitting it with a ping-pong ball. It just won't move a noticeable amount. If WIMPs are very heavy, there are fewer of them around. (We know the approximate total *mass density* of dark matter in our neighborhood, so the *number density* is smaller at higher mass.) Fewer dark matter particles around means a smaller likelihood of interaction in the detector. So the limit is best when the WIMPs are heavy enough to produce recoils above threshold, and light enough that the number density is not too small.

Comment: won't heavier WIMPS also transfer less momentum to the target nuclei? similar to electron vs muon in a calorimeter?

Comment: No. WIMP-nucleus interactions are generally more like hard-sphere contact interactions. It isn't really analogous to things like bremsstrahlung, where electrons lose some energy in a material.

Comment: thanks. I think I've misunderstood something basic! - if I look at a 2-body elastic scatter with one object initially at rest e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_collision#Two-_and_three-dimensional if the incoming object is very, there will be no momentum transfer...

Comment: doesn't that apply to very heavy WIMPs in DD experiments? maybe my reference to electrons vs muons is a bad one.

Comment: The relative velocity is determined by the speed of DM orbiting the galactic center, roughly $v_0 \approx 220$ km/s, independent of the mass. Even for heavy DM, I think you can get momentum transfer of order $m_{\rm nucleus} v_0$, if I'm not making a stupid mistake.